# Concentration of the quotient of random variables

Tags: pr.probability, measure-concentration

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ be n i.i.d. standard Gaussian random variables. It is clear that we can describe the concentration of $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i X_i$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i X_i^2$ (sub-exponential property), where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb R^+$ is the weight.

How to describe the concentration of $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i X_i^2}?$$

Comment: What does "describe the concentration" mean? Can you state, what exactly do you want to prove?

Comment: State a tail bound for the quotient around zero (of course zero is the mean of the quotient), or an anti-concentration result.

Comment: $P(I>t)=P(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i(X_i+t(1-X_i^2))>t||\alpha||_1)$ and you can apply the usual Hoeffding/Chernoff techniques.